# All references broken in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2022

In my job, I am working with some older C# code and trying to resurrect some of it. For a lot of these projects, it's worked fine, but with at least one of them, every single reference is broken. These are all references which definitely do exist (other projects reference them with no issue). I have tried removing and readding the references, and nothing changes--they are immediately broken upon reference. I have also tried changing the target framework, creating a reference path, deleting the .vs folder, and deleting the obj folder. None of these steps have made any difference. Does anyone have any input? I would be greatly appreciative.

What I tried:

- Removing and readding the references
- Creating a reference path in the project's properties
- Changing the target framework in the project's properties
- Deleting the .vs and obj folders